Would reverse voltage kill the optocoupler over long time period?
I got this circuit:

The circuit detects the 250 VAC voltage when it is present using the optocoupler. There would be a reverse voltage on both LEDs as the input AC alternates, although the current will be low (near V peak will be approximately 1.5 mA.) The condition of the circuit could change to 1.7 or 1.8 mA depending on the AC input.  Could the reverse voltage occurring while AC alternates destroy the LEDs over long period times?

The anti parallel arrangement of the diodes ensures the voltage across the opto's input is clamped on each half cycle.
During each half cycle, one of the anti-parallel diodes conducts, and whilst it's conducting it limits the voltage across the input, therefore the other's reverse voltage, to its forward drop.


And the current is limited by the 240 kΩ resistance. So no, the opto will not be destroyed during normal operation.

The LEDs should protect each other. One is always forward biased, which means the voltage across it is never going to be more than 1.4V according to the datasheet (should be even less as it is defined @20mA and your current is less). And this forward voltage is simultaneously reverse voltage for the other LED, so it is very low.

No, there will be no damage as there can never be enough reverse voltage to damage the reverse biased LED because one diode must then be forwars biased.
This is why the data shet does not even mention the maximum input reverse bias because it cannot be reached.
Typical maximum reverse bias for a normal optoisolator would be around 5V and in this case the LEDs must anyway be operated at below 1.6V which cannot cause damage to the reverse biased LED.

Indeed, a typical GaAlAs emitter breaks down well beyond the 5V rating; I've measured a few over 100V.
